# Partial derivatives of $f(x_1, \dots, x_n, g(x_1, \dots, x_n))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have some arbitrary differentiable function of $n+1$ variables, $f(x_1, \dots, x_n, y)$, and some other arbitrary differentiable function of $n$ variables, $g(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. I then define a new function of $n$ variables:
$$
h(x_1, \dots, x_n) = f\left(x_1, \dots, x_n, g(x_1, \dots, x_n)\right).
$$
I would like to be able to express the partial derivatives $\partial h/\partial x_i$ in terms of $f$, $g$ and their partial derivatives. It seems I need something a bit like the multivariable chain rule, but slightly different, and I'm not sure how to obtain it. Can anyone help?

Comment: $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}$

Comment: @ShuchangZhang that looks right - but how can I derive it?

Comment: $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}$. But $\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i}=\delta^k_i$

Comment: @ShuchangZhang got it, thanks. Feel free to post that as an answer if you'd like the points.

Comment: Well, since you say it. Ironically, I just came up with [how to avoid answered questions in unanswered list](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11692/answered-questions-in-unanswered-list/11705?noredirect=1#11705), but I was making one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows directly from chain rule
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}\delta^k_i+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}$$